# How to select a specific column in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

I am new to machine learning. I have downloaded a breast cancer data set to try to make a classification on it.

When I try to print the head function (data.head()) I get this

```
id;diagnosis;radius_mean;texture_mean;perimeter_mean;area_mean;smoothness_mean;compactness_mean;concavity_mean;concave points_mean;symmetry_mean;fractal_dimension_mean;radius_se;texture_se;perimeter_se;area_se;smoothness_se;compactness_se;concavity_se;concave points_se;symmetry_se;fractal_dimension_se;radius_worst;texture_worst;perimeter_worst;area_worst;smoothness_worst;compactness_worst;concavity_worst;concave points_worst;symmetry_worst;fractal_dimension_worst
```

When I try to make the id column the labels using the following code code :

```
train_labels = data['id'].values
```

it doesn't work. Instead it shows this long error message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\win10\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ';id'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-23e840b4d870> in <module>
----> 1 train_labels = data[';id'].values

C:\Users\win10\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2978             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2979                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2980             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2981             if is_integer(indexer):
   2982                 indexer = [indexer]

C:\Users\win10\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'id'
```

So how can I get any specific column in my data set?

Comment: Please, paste the code you've used for reading the data from the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've read the file using a at least a wrong separator (`sep`). By default [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) uses `,` and in `data.head()` `;` separators are visible. If you are using `pd.read_csv`, try passing `sep=';'`.

The code you are using for accessing a specific column (`data['id']`) seems otherwise correct.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The dataset is not comma separated, but it's semicolon separated so you have to pass a parameter in read_csv function which is sep =';' and this will solve your problem.

```
data = pd.read_csv('file_name', sep = ';')
data['column_name']
```

You'll be able to fetch the column for this dataset.